# Configuring Hiera on Puppet Enterprise

Tags: puppet, hiera, puppet-enterprise

I am new to Puppet and Hiera, and having a configuration issue when attempting to apply a module the contains a Hiera lookup to an agent.

From /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
  :datadir: '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera'
```

From /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera/develop.yaml:

```
git_client:
    file_content:here
```

When running Hiera to debug:

/opt/puppet/bin/hiera git_client environment=develop -c /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml --debug

```
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Looking up git_client in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Looking for data source defaults
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Cannot find datafile /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera/defaults.yaml, skipping
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Looking for data source develop
DEBUG: 2015-05-12 12:40:27 -0400: Found git_client in develop
file_content:here
```

Windows agent configuration from puppet.conf:

```
[main]
server=[REDACTED]
pluginsync=true
autoflush=true
archive_files=true
archive_file_server=[REDACTED]
graph=true
environment=develop
```

But when running from the Windows agent:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item git_client in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/develop/modules/[REDACTED PATH TO .pp FILE]:24 on node [REDACTED]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I must have something misconfigured, but I'm not sure where. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show me the `puppet.conf` file on windows agent.

Comment: what version of PE. if you are using the pe-puppetserver did you restart it? or if you are using the passenger puppet master did you restart that? i have found that when making changes to a hiera config file you typically need to bounce your master.

Comment: @BMW, I added the puppet.conf from the Windows agent.

Comment: @ptierno, you are correct, restarting the pe-puppetserver resolved the issue. If you respond I'll mark accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for changes to your `hiera` configuration to take effect, you need to make sure to restart your `puppet master`. If you are using the `puppetserver` that runs in the `JVM` then restart the `pe-puppetserver` service. If you are using the old `ruby` master running on `passenger`, then restart `pe-httpd`.

Taken from the [hiera docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html):

> Puppet master note: If you modify hiera.yaml between agent runs, you’ll have to restart your puppet master for your changes to take effect.